# How is the right way to add additional commands by git pull using plesk obsidian

Tags: git, plesk

i tried to pull git repos in Plesk Obsidian and want to run composer (and other..) commands after pull.

1. setting up the repo settings in Plesk is not the problem. All works fine.
2. I can 'Enable additional deployment actions' and can insert some commands in this field. in my case `composer install`. I saw this command is not run or maybe run with errors.

My Question is: Where i can find the log of this commands and what is the correct syntax of this command. I cant found any actual docs to this topic.

Thx for your time and help.